# Overriding a method which requires raw type parametrization

Tags: java, overriding, raw-types

OK here is my question: I have a abstract superclass which contains a method public `double[][] extractFeatures(BufferedImage image) throws Exception`.

I want to override it (that is, to have my implementation of the subclass being called when I define a subclass object). The problem is that the implementation I am using needs a raw type parametrization like `<II extends ImageSingleBand>` in order to function correctly (otherwise there are errors). So now the signature becomes:

```
public <II extends ImageSingleBand> double[][] extractFeatures(BufferedImage image)
```

The problem is that Java compilers gives me a name clash noting that it has the

> same erasure but does not override it

A fact that might help is that in the subclass `extractFeatures()` method when I do not use the raw type parametrization the error occur when the code declares a variable:

```
Class<II> integralType = ...
```

Changing that to `Class<II extends ImageSingleBand> integralType = ...` did not solve the problem either.

I know that I can skip this problem by various ways:

- (a) Renaming `extractFeatures()` of the subclass (I can use it in my case by I would prefer a more consistent solution)
- (b) Moving all parts that need the raw type parametrization to another function that can be called inside the subclass `extractFeatures()` (that is the solution the previous code writer chose),
  so I am not asking for a solution that works rather to clarify the situation

My question is whether there is a way to solve this without using a bypass solution like the previously mentioned or that erasure issue ties my hands.

Comment: Why would one want to give a subclass-method the same name as a base class-method, when the subclass-method implements new behavior which doesn't match or re-uses the base class-behaviour? This design could lead to dramatic misunderstanding of your API.

Comment: For a method to override another it needs to have exactly the same arguments. It is allowed to be covariant in the return type. I.e. it must be applicable in all the situations where the overridden method would be. I don't see you using the type argument `II` in the method signature anyway - why do you need it?

Comment: @Smutje it may be the case (bad design after all) but I did not design the project from the beginning so adding new features lead me here. I am learning after all.

Comment: @Boris, well I do not use it the signature but it is necessary for the compiler to proceed the part `Class<II> integralType = ...`.

Comment: And why can't your type bound go there? There seems no reason for it to in the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to stay away from sub-classing, and go for using a design pattern suited for this task such as Adapter.

The whole point of Adapter, is to implement a certain interface (in your case, the parametrized method), which using a different interface module/class/method to do the actual work (in your case, the non-parametrized method).

The actual implementation of the Adapter, is to do any adaptations needs between the interfaces to the input parameters, call the actual implementer, adapt the results according to the output type, and return the result.

More on this can be found at: [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)